# Adding time stamp to log file in bash script

Tags: bash, time

My script is as follows

```
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep ./program > /dev/null
    then
        exit
    else
        echo "---------------------------------------------------" >> Debug.log
        echo "Starting program at:  $(date)" >> Debug.log
        ./program >> Debug.log 2>&1
fi
exit
```

Via crontab, this script is run every minute. It checks to see if a certain program is running, if it is, great, if not, starts it up.

Now I would like to append timestamps every time the script runs into Debug.log if it found ./program to be running. So under the `then` line, I added:

```
echo "Time: $(date)" >> Debug.log
```

This command does not output anything to Debug.log. It does work however directly from the command line. Why is that so, and can I remedy the problem?

Comment: Cannot tell you why, but `date +"Time: %C" >>Debug.log` would seem to do what you want, probably more transparently and succinctly.

Comment: Also, `grep thing | grep -v grep` can usually be refactored to something like `grep [t]hing` where the idea is to use a regex which does not match itself.

Comment: Note you are outputting to `Debug.log`, while you should indicate the full path of that file.

Comment: @fedorqui this is what it ended up being. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Note you are outputting to `Debug.log`, while you should indicate the full path of that file: `echo "Time: $(date)" >> /path/to/Debug.log`.

---

In general, whenever you want to add timestamp to a log file, you can use:

```
echo "Time: $(date). Some error info." >> /path/to/your/file.log
```

`date` will expand to something like `Fri Sep  9 12:18:02 CEST 2016`. In that case, you may prefer to use some `date` flags to have a more parseable date:

```
$ date "+%FT%T"
2016-09-09T12:18:23
```

Or, even better, using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format:

```
$ date -Iseconds
2016-09-09T12:18:23+0200
```

All together:

```
echo "Time: $(date -Iseconds). Some error info." >> /path/to/your/file.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Possible reason is different paths for date in terminal and sh: try using full path to the date which you use directly from command line, i.e. `$(/bin/date)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @{fedorqui 'SO stop harming'} using `>>` appends to the end of the log file.

Alternatively, this will also limit the log to 1MB:

```
tail -c 1MB fail.log; echo $(date) run script > file.log
```